# Code is refusing to define ranges on activesheets that are not sheet1

Tags: excel, vba

I have a listbox on sheet1 with a list of sheetnames. When somebody double clicks on a name in the list, the code is supposed to activate that sheet, select some data and create a graph out of it.

The code is fine, right up until I ask it to define a range on the other sheet. I've had a number of different error messages and as best I can tell, the code is simply refusing to do anything that is not on sheet1. If somebody could explain why, that would be brilliant.

Code: the listbox is called Stocklist

```
Option Explicit

Sub StockList_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)

Call stockgraph

End Sub

Private Sub stockgraph()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim stockrange As Range
Dim daterange As Range
Dim security_name As String
Dim finalrow As Integer
Dim stockarray() As Double
Dim datearray() As String
Dim cell As Range

security_name = Empty

security_name = StockList.Value

If security_name = Empty Then MsgBox ("something's gone wrong, excel doesn't recognise that value") ' DEBUG

Worksheets(security_name).Activate ' --> this bit works fine
finalrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).row ' --> as does this

Set stockrange = Sheets(security_name).Range(Cells(2, 3), Cells(finalrow, 3))
' --> This gives a 1004 error, so does using activesheet
' --> if I don't reference a sheet, despite it not being the activesheet, the ranges are defined on sheet1
' --> and yet, the code was perfectly fine defining finalrow

Set daterange = Sheets(security_name).Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(finalrow, 1))

ReDim stockarray(1 To finalrow - 1) As Double ' row 1 is a header so 2 to finalrow = 1 to finalrow-1
ReDim datearray(1 To finalrow - 1) As String

    For Each cell In stockrange
        stockarray(cell.row - 1) = cell.Value
    Next cell

    For Each cell In daterange
        datearray(cell.row - 1) = cell.text
    Next cell

Sheets("Top 10 holdings").Activate

' Create graph
    Dim c As Chart
    Dim s1 As Series

    ActiveSheet.Cells(50, 50) = stockarray

    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select

    Set c = ActiveChart
    Set s1 = c.SeriesCollection(1)

    c.ChartType = xlLine
    s1.Values = stockarray


Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: After removing the quotes from the variable names this works absolutely fine for me in Excel 2010, both arrays are populated with data.  What version of Excel are you running?  What is the typical size of the range?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot construct a cell range reference in that manner without fully qualifying the internal cell references used as demarcation points.

```
With Sheets(security_name)
    finalrow = .Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).row
    Set stockrange = .Range(.Cells(2, 3), .Cells(finalrow, 3))
    Set daterange = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(finalrow, 1))
End With
```